# ElasticSearch - Search Multiple Indexes and Correlate/Aggregate results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch and trying to figure out the best way to achieve the following:

I have 2 indexes :

- Processes
- Tasks

Tasks are a child of Processes, but this hasn't been implemented on the Elastic Search side, as far as elastic search is aware these are 2 independent indexes. There is however a compositeId field which is consistent between processes and tasks.

Now, I would like to search for tasks (and return its process data) for given attributes on both Task and Process. In the relational world I would do a join between the 2 on the compositeId and specify my conditions in the Where clause. Is this achievable in an efficient way in Elastic?

I'm aware that the best option would probably be to produce an additional/alternative index that includes both datasets and query that way, but I am trying to see if I can achieve the above using the OOTB 'event emitters'.

Thanks

Comment: Basically, Elasticsearch doesn't enable performing joins between indices. Nevertheless there exist some solutions, but we'll need a bit more information to help : (1) Can you ( / are you allowed to) change your mapping ? (2) is your ``compositeId`` field the document technical identifier from Elasticsearch perspective ?

Comment: 1. No I cannot change the existing mapping.

Comment: 2. Yes, the compositeId is the technical Id in elastic. 

thanks

Comment: Sorry @gravityBlast, after taking a look at the documentation, there are 3 workarounds : ParentChild queries and nested fields require you to change your mapping and terms lookups won't be helpful for your use case :(  (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html)

Comment: thanks @baitmbarek I thought as much, but thought I'd ask. The other option I was looking at was performing multiple searches in a single API hit and performing the necessary aggregation ideally at the Elasticsearch level, but I could do application level if need be. Do you know if this is possible? Thanks